# dc.js / crossfilter dimensions (year / week)

Tags: d3.js, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

I can't make a correct graph showing the data group by week (and different years).

pseudo SQL would give:

```
select sum ('task')
group by 'year', 'week' (and maybe later 'site')
```

My data looks more or less like this:

```
{ "date" : "20150427", "week" : 18, "site" : "a" "task" : 3, } 
{ "date" : "20150427", "week" : 18, "site" : "b" "task" : 4, } 
{ "date" : "20150427", "week" : 18, "site" : "c" "task" : 2, } 
{ "date" : "20150427", "week" : 18, "site" : "d" "task" : 3, } 
{ "date" : "20150428", "week" : 18, "site" : "a" "task" : 3, } 
{ "date" : "20150428", "week" : 18, "site" : "b" "task" : 3, } 
{ "date" : "20150429", "week" : 18, "site" : "c" "task" : 2, } 
{ "date" : "20150429", "week" : 18, "site" : "d" "task" : 3, } 
{ "date" : "20140512", "week" : 20, "site" : "d" "task" : 6, } 
{ "date" : "20140512", "week" : 20, "site" : "a" "task" : 6, } 
{ "date" : "20140513", "week" : 20, "site" : "b" "task" : 4, } 
{ "date" : "20140513", "week" : 20, "site" : "c" "task" : 1, } 
{ "date" : "20140519", "week" : 21, "site" : "b" "task" : 2, } 
{ "date" : "20140519", "week" : 21, "site" : "c" "task" : 1, } 
{ "date" : "20140519", "week" : 21, "site" : "d" "task" : 3, } 
{ "date" : "20140519", "week" : 21, "site" : "a" "task" : 1, } 
{ "date" : "20140520", "week" : 21, "site" : "b" "task" : 2, } 
{ "date" : "20140520", "week" : 21, "site" : "c" "task" : 3, } 
{ "date" : "20140520", "week" : 21, "site" : "d" "task" : 1, } 
{ "date" : "20140520", "week" : 21, "site" : "a" "task" : 1, }
```

This is a sample of my data, it can have different years, sites or tasks

I tried this and it doesn't work, because the barChart cumulates the week of all years:

```
d3.json("/graph", function(dataJson) {


var dataTable = dc.dataTable("#dc-table-graph");
var barChart  = dc.barChart("#chart-bar-ordersperweek");

var data = dataJson;
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d");
data.forEach(function (d) { d.date = dateFormat.parse(d.date); });


//dimension
var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.date; });
var weekDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.week;});

//group
var orderByWD = weekDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.task; });


barChart
    .width(1000).height(250)
    .dimension(weekDim)
    .group(orderByWD)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(minWeek.week-1,maxWeek.week+1)))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 6000]))
    .margins({top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 80})
    .label(function(d) { return d.value})
    ;


dataTable.width(800).height(800)
        .dimension(dateDim)     
        .group( function (d) { return 'Week ' + d.week} )
        .size(5000)
        .columns([
            function (d) { var format = d3.format('02d');
                return d.date.getFullYear() +'/'+ format(d.date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + format(d.date.getDate()); },
            function (d) { return d.week; },
            function (d) { return d.site; },
            function (d) { return d.task; }
        ])
        .sortBy( function (d) { return Number(d.date) + d.task; })
        .order(d3.descending);

        dataTable.on('renderlet', function(chart){
            chart.selectAll('.dc-table-group').classed('info',true);
        });

dc.renderAll();
```

**My goal** is to sum all task happened in same week and draw it to row chart and when I select a week that update the datatable with selected week.

In the dataTable how do I sum (cumulate) task by site grouped by week ?

Thanks for any help

**EDIT**
i have add a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/d4qsd8wh/

Comment: I think dataTable runs based on dimension rather than group, so you'll probably need to create a fake dimension that returns the records you want to display. If you put together a working example using jsfiddle or something similar, I or someone else here can probably get it working for you.

Comment: i just add it
https://jsfiddle.net/d4qsd8wh/

Answer (score 1):

So, what you'll want to do is create a fake "dimension" for the dataTable. In your current approach you can do it like this:

```
// Actually a dimension keyed on week and site
var fakeDateDim = {
  top: function(d) {
    var m = dc.d3.map();
    dateDim.top(Infinity).forEach(function(g) {
      if(m.has(g.week + g.site)) {
        m.get(g.week + g.site).task += g.task
      } else {
        // Create the "record"
        m.set(g.week + g.site, {
            week: g.week,
          site: g.site,
          task: g.task
        })
      }
    })

    return m.values();
  }
}
```

Then in the dataTable, use that `fakeDateDim` in the place of your current `dateDim`. (You'll also have to remove the table columns for date and week.)

Here's a working example based on the example you put together: https://jsfiddle.net/s2c9rhxw/

Note that you can use d3.nest, as mentioned in the answer by @ian-h, but it masks some of what you are doing, so I think it's probably better to use lower-level constructs like Map or d3.map until you are comfortable with the calculation. Regardless of how you actually execute the calculation, the key is to wrap it in a fake dimension object that dc.js will be able to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I've got the question right, since the other answers seem to be solving different problems. I will assume you're just asking how to get group-by-week to work when the week entry on your fields does not specify the year - so you get weeks from different years piled into one.

In other words I interpret this as the heart of your question:

> I tried this and it doesn't work, because the barChart cumulates the week of all years

Which isn't really about the dataTable but the barChart.

To answer that question: yes, I think your `week` field is useless. Instead, use the parsed dates and `d3.time.week` to bin by week:

```
var weekDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d3.time.week(d.date);});
```

Then set your bar chart to use date units instead of ordinals:

```
barChart
    ...
    .x(d3.time.scale())
    .xUnits(d3.time.weeks)
    .elasticX(true) // or calculate minWeek/maxWeek using date objects
```

What `d3.time.week` does, like the other [d3 time interval functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals), is return the date which is at the beginning of the interval. (Since `d3.time.week` is a synonym for `d3.time.sunday`, it returns midnight on the Sunday before each date - use `d3.time.monday` if you want Monday-based weeks instead.) Clipping each date to the beginning of its interval is a good way to bin the dates without forgetting the year they are a part of.

Then `d3.time.weeks` (notice the `s`) is a related function which can count the number of intervals (weeks) within any time range. dc.js needs an  `xUnits` counting function in order to determine the number of bars to show.

Given that you've gotten answers to three different questions, you might want to spend a minute refining your next question to make sure it's clear.

Comment: I think there may have been multiple questions. Maybe we can put together an omnibus answer :-)

Comment: ok, that solve a part of my problem :)
but how i can define 'monday' as start of week (currently Sunday is the first day) ?

_is this part d3.time.week(d.date)_

thank for your help Gordon

Comment: Great, I hope some of the other answers are helpful too! [d3.time.week](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals#week) is just a synonym for `d3.time.sunday` so you should be able to use `d3.time.monday` to get what you want. I'll clarify what this does above.

Comment: for cosmetic, what i have to change to have weeks in label rather than months ?
exemple: week 1 ... week 5 ... week 10 ...

Answer (score 0):

D3 has some pretty powerful tools to help you shape your data. This is just an example. By making a key of the Year+Week we can sum the tasks

```
var out = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.date.substring(0,4)+d.week; })
  .rollup(function(v) { return {
      date: v[0].date,
      task: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.task; })
     };
   })
  .entries(data);
```

That will make `out` an array of objects that looks like this.

```
[
  {
    "key": "201420",
    "values": {
      "date": "20140512",
      "task": 17
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "201421",
    "values": {
      "date": "20140519",
      "task": 14
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "201518",
    "values": {
      "date": "20150427",
      "task": 23
    }
  }
]
```

Since you are grouping by week then the date is mostly arbitrary so I just have it showing the first one in the list of grouped dates. You can also add another `.key(function(d) { return d.site; }` under the first `.key` to sub group by site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your weekDim as follows:

```
var weekDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.date.substring(0,4) + "" + d.week;
});
```

and then create group on this dimension as follows:

```
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
    return p + v.task;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
    return p - v.task;
}

function reduceInitial() {
    return 0;
}
var m = weekDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd,reduceRemove,reduceInitial);
```

and you get the result as m.top(Infinity).
I don't know how you can use this dataTable but the output of the above will be exactly what you want.
Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is helpful. This reduction is equivalent to the `reduceSum` in the question, and d3 has better ways of dealing with time. Thanks for contributing!